# EF Core migration adds cascade on delete in wrong direction for one to many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am using `asp.net core 3 web api` and `EF core 3` I have a `one to many` relationship between 2 tables:

`Task` and `TaskType`

`Task` has one `TaskType`

`TaskType` has many `Tasks`

Here are the 2 entities:

```
public class TaskType
{
    public TaskType() {
        Tasks = new HashSet<Task>();
    }

    [Key]
    public Guid TaskTypeID { get;set; }
    ...
    public ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
} 

public class Task
{
    public Task() {

    }

    [Key]
    public Guid TaskID {get;set;}
    ...
    public Guid TaskTypeID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TaskTypeID")]
    public TaskType TaskType { get; set; }
}
```

When I run the `add-migration` command it generates this code

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.AddColumn<Guid>(
        name: "TaskTypeID",
        table: "Task",
        nullable: false,
        defaultValue: new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"));

    migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
        name: "IX_Task_TaskTypeID",
        table: "Task",
        column: "TaskTypeID");

    migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
        name: "FK_Task_TaskType_TaskTypeID",
        table: "Task",
        column: "TaskTypeID",
        principalTable: "TaskType",
        principalColumn: "TaskTypeID",
        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Delete);// I want to change this to ReferentialAction.NoAction
}

protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
        name: "FK_Task_TaskType_TaskTypeID",
        table: "Task");

    migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
        name: "IX_Task_TaskTypeID",
        table: "Task");

    migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
        name: "TaskTypeID",
        table: "Task");
}
```

Notice the line `onDelete: ReferentialAction.Delete` which obviously is an error and should cascade the other way.

To fix this, I want to change it to `ReferentialAction.NoAction`

and add this code to my `onModelCreating` in my context

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TaskType>()
            .HasMany(c => c.Tasks)
            .WithOne(e => e.TaskType)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

Is this the correct way to add cascade delete for a one to many relationship? Should I be modifying the generated migration code or is there another way to tell EF not to cascade delete the `TaskType` when I delete a `Task`?

Edit:
The accepted answer helped me come up with ha solution. I should have been more specific, I needed the orphaned `TaskType` records. So I set the `TaskTypeID` FK to a nullable `Guid` and in my `OnDelete()` I set the option to `ReferentialAction.SetNull`

Comment: The default value for arguments **onUpdate** and **onDelete** is **ReferentialAction.Noaction**

Take at look at this documentation.
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.migrationbuilder.addforeignkey?view=efcore-3.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direction is correct.

If you were to delete a `Task` by cascading from the delete of a `TaskType` then you could quite possibly leave a lot of orphaned `TaskType` records (assuming there was no referential integrity).

The entity `TaskType` depends on the `Task` entity, so the only valid scsenario for deleting a `Task` is to delete all of the associated `TaskType` records.

One common approach to getting around this is to use a *soft* delete.

Essentially add a property to the entity

`public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }`

and you can then know that an entity is deleted, but still maintain the correct references.

Comment: I will also would like to add a link to the documentation of cascade delete. If this were another case, it may be on by default. https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/cascade-delete-in-code-first.aspx#:~:targetText=Cascade%20delete%20automatically%20deletes%20dependent,and%20many%2Dto%2Dmany.

Comment: Thanks this put me in the right direction, I should have been more specific. I needed the cascade on delete from `Taskype -> Task` because I wanted the orphaned `TaskType` records. So I kept my code as is and changed the  generated delelete to `ReferentialAction.SetNull`. And my foreign key to `Guid?`

Comment: That will work assuming it is a valid scenario to have a `TaskType` without an associated `Task`